# Controlling layout of dynamically added controls in asp:panel

Tags: asp.net

I'm adding a serires of asp:literal and asp:textbox controls to a panel in code as below (the eventual aim being to add only some of the controls depending on the user):

```
    With Me.pnl1
        Controls.Add(FirstLiteral)
        Controls.Add(FirstTxtBox)
        Controls.Add(SecondLiteral)
        Controls.Add(SecondTxtBox)
        Controls.Add(ThirdLiteral)
        Controls.Add(ThirdTxtBox)
    End With
```

The intention is to have each control on its own line but I'm getting a mixed up layout like so:

```
FirstLiteral
FirstTxtbox SecondLiteral
SecondTxtbox thirdLiteral
thirdtxtbox
```

How can I control how the panel is rendered, preferably without having to create a custom control?

Thanks,
Patrick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each control added You will have to add something like

```
pnl.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put mark up in the literals:

```
Private Sub doSearchPanel()
        LitTxtUsername.Text = GetLocalResourceObject("TxtUsernameResource1.text") + "<br/>"
        ltNameSearch.Text = "<br/>" + GetLocalResourceObject("ltNameSearch.text") + "<br/>"
        ltGroupSearch.Text = "<br/>" + GetLocalResourceObject("ltGroupSearch.text") + "<br/>"
        'With Me.pnlSearch
        Me.pnlSearch.Controls.Add(Me.LitTxtUsername)
        Me.pnlSearch.Controls.Add(Me.txtMatch)
        Me.pnlSearch.Controls.Add(Me.ltNameSearch)
        Me.pnlSearch.Controls.Add(Me.txtNameSearch)
        Me.pnlSearch.Controls.Add(Me.ltGroupSearch)
        Me.pnlSearch.Controls.Add(Me.txtGroupSearch)
        'End With
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a "closing" literal after each textbox containing a `<br />`
Or you could add an "opening" literal before each line (`<div>` ) and a closing one (`</div>`)